# Exporting 3D Images from C++ to Matlab .fig files

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a visual analytics program that handles the visualization of 3D datasets (e.g., MRI datasets). For multiple reasons, I want to be able to watch the result (3D-grid image visualizable using ray tracking techniques, e.g., the ray-marching algorithm) in Matlab. I see that Matlab relies on .fig files, but I do not find any documentation of its structure.

Does people know where .fig files are documented? Is there any C++ library that proposes such a functionality? My C++ code runs on a linux workstation and I do not own any Matlab license: the generated files are not meant to me but to others owning such a license.

Thanks!

Comment: `.fig` files are internal MATLAB GUI data. If instead of the commercially (and freely) available medical imaging visualization software, you want to use MATLAB (which I do), then just import it in MATLAB using any format (i.e. tiff, dicom, png, whatever) and then withing MATLAB, use/write code to visualize your data. `.fig` is a misleading clue, forget abou them.

Comment: I understand. I hope I can load binary 3D vector in Matlab then ^^'

Comment: You can load anything in MATLAB. MATLAB may or may not natively support it, but MATLAB is turing-complete, you can do anything that other languages can do.